# Could not get the full response of the body of URL

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a basic socket programming code in python which takes any kind of URL and returns the content of the body in bytes. I need to only use **socket** library and nothing else. When I pass different URLs, I get full response of the body for some URLs and only a partial response for some URLs. I'm not sure why it is so.

This is my code:

```
import socket


def retrieve_url(url):

    url1 = url.split("http://", 1)
    empty = url1[1].find("/")
    if empty > 0:
        url2 = url1[1].split("/", 1)
    else:
        url2 = url1[1].split("/", 1)
        url2.append('')

    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        soc.connect((url2[0], 80))
        soc.sendall(b"GET /" + bytes(url2[1], 'utf8') + b" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + bytes(url2[0],'utf8') + b"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
        spl = soc.recv(8192)
        soc.close()
        a = spl.split(b"\r\n\r\n", 1)
        b = spl.split(None, 2)
        if b[1] == b'200':
            return a[1]
        else:
            return None
    except:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(retrieve_url("http://bombus.myspecies.info/node/24"))
```

This is the output I'm getting:

`b'007a84\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">\n<html lang="en" dir="ltr" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"\n  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"\n  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"\n  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"\n  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"\n  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"\n  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"\n  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"\n  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"\n  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">\n<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">\n  <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />\n<![endif]--><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />\n<link rel="canonical" href="/node/24" />\n<link rel="shortlink" href="/node/24" />\n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://bombus.myspecies.info/sites/all/themes/scratchpads/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />\n  <title>Bumblebee links | Genus Bombus</title>\n  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_css/css__-thr5kmN-aeH-BTlyCidKsE4D9T2geiRzcvwxBTJ3sU__VQtLPGzb9rjfNLJ2SaVDJUKhxtssNArRk3nO7wMUGoA__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.css" media="all" />\n\n<!--[if (lt IE 9)]>\n<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_css/css__GuBcvhFB_-fswxhbycYya2JRgqrqDq5y-pWYcuQbqp4__5h6_elrgEAXONSci50a6ewD4zUldIVoOgFFSjk7rVzg__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.css" media="all" />\n<![endif]-->\n<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_css/css__wxRBHPf0PIq6kCJXm57TkZCESl8zp_O0VduSG6wH0S0__ov4XZtBPHqH1F5cpK65jxEp1K5zF3dLEO4ihA2xTbE8__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.css" media="all" />\n\n<!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>\n<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_css/css__ISa-1zfLkp-52D_pPloP6gBpDvJwKu9Kitwbfnm33JY__PDj463LZhTo68R-x__a4AOf-EyYxSMW6sZpiNjtiKlQ__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.css" media="all" />\n<![endif]-->\n\n<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->\n<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_css/css__Sisgbo-UreLp3cHBWfv37bIck8X5olI1W5xaYzDaATc__9XoSDv750KzHbfRkMww8VsZREmLh-SRR3SnhCYOEF2Q__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.css" media="all" />\n<!--<![endif]-->\n  <script type="text/javascript" src="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_js/js__jQBI8pfG-VfYV1aN0gSeRXUYps9-4-M-XVb2H2ZbWuw__SyNVdbb0UiBMvI1oo0AzTY4CH83E7BmTR7ZP1Wwz_VE__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.js"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/all/libraries/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js?v=2.1.6"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="//bombus.myspecies.info/sites/bombus.myspecies.info/files/advagg_js/js__O2-Mfrpb6mHF0S5LAfIan_d38-kqXvv66sN_ZsHG9Qo__caMiUBuMxDF7rNYJXFf8geEVfuxGw22B96ouV1h3-1Q__CirpVkWrddCrpKWbZfWXvbwVN8pmqviBo8YZAKaYUQg.js"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript">\n<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--\njQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,{"basePath":"\\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"scratchpads","theme_token":"u7Gd7GPT7EPAVsIznB6HVhd9aHAwVUfjG4LrulLh3ak","jquery_version":"1.8","css":{"modules\\/system\\/system.base.css":1,"modules\\/system\\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\\/system\\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\\/system\\/system.theme.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/libraries\\/mediaelement\\/build\\/mediaelementplayer.min.css":1,"misc\\/ui\\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,"misc\\/ui\\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,"modules\\/overlay\\/overlay-parent.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/comment_notify\\/comment_notify.css":1,"modules\\/aggregator\\/aggregator.css":1,"modules\\/comment\\/comment.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/date\\/date_api\\/date.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/entityfilter\\/ckeditor\\/entityfilter.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/field_quick_delete\\/theme\\/field.css":1,"modules\\/node\\/node.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/remote_issue_tab\\/css\\/remote_issue_tab.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/scratchpads\\/scratchpads_biography\\/css\\/scratchpads_biography.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/scratchpads\\/scratchpads_show_taxa_revisions\\/css\\/scratchpads_show_taxa_revisions.css":1,"modules\\/search\\/search.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/spm\\/css\\/spm.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/twitter_filter\\/css\\/twitter_filter.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/twitterscript\\/css\\/twitterscript.css":1,"modules\\/user\\/user.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/views\\/css\\/views.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/ckeditor\\/ckeditor.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/colorbox\\/styles\\/default\\/colorbox_default_style.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/ctools\\/css\\/ctools.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/ctools\\/css\\/modal.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/modal_forms\\/css\\/modal_forms_popup.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/biblio\\/biblio.css":1,"modules\\/openid\\/openid.css":1,"public:\\/\\/spamicide\\/feed_me.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/scratchpads\\/scratchpads_search_block\\/css\\/scratchpads_search_block.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/custom\\/creative_commons\\/css\\/creative_commons.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/ie8.css":1,"public:\\/\\/css\\/css_tcVOMdlRmJTsBkm7ZJABjZ3Oct1H-tB7QsRkmUkgNco.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/tabs.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/sites.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/alpha-reset.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/alpha-mobile.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/alpha-alpha.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/omega\\/css\\/formalize.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/omega\\/css\\/omega-text.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/omega\\/css\\/omega-branding.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/omega\\/css\\/omega-menu.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/omega\\/css\\/omega-forms.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/global.css":1,"ie::normal::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default.css":1,"ie::normal::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default-normal.css":1,"ie::normal::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/grid\\/alpha_default\\/normal\\/alpha-default-normal-12.css":1,"narrow::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default.css":1,"narrow::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default-narrow.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/grid\\/alpha_default\\/narrow\\/alpha-default-narrow-12.css":1,"normal::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default.css":1,"normal::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default-normal.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/grid\\/alpha_default\\/normal\\/alpha-default-normal-12.css":1,"wide::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default.css":1,"wide::sites\\/all\\/themes\\/scratchpads\\/css\\/scratchpads-alpha-default-wide.css":1,"sites\\/all\\/themes\\/omega\\/alpha\\/css\\/grid\\/alpha_default\\/wide\\/alpha-default-wide-12.css":1},"js":{"modules\\/statistics\\/statistics.js":1,"sites\\/all\\/modules\\/contrib\\/jquer'`

***I only get partial response for this, but what I need is the full response.***

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    soc.sendall(b"GET /" + bytes(url2[1], 'utf8') + b" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + bytes(url2[0],'utf8') + b"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
    spl = soc.recv(8192)
    soc.close()
```

You assume that all data will be retrieved with a single `recv`. This assumption is wrong. Given that you use an explicit `Connection: close` you can rely on the server closing the connection after the response is done, i.e. you should call `recv` as long as it returns more data and concatenate all these date for the full response.

You also assume that the answer is contained in plain in the response body. While this might be true in your specific case your use of `HTTP/1.1` makes it possible for the server to send a chunked response too - which you need to handle differently. In order to avoid this better use `HTTP/1.0` only (which also has an implicit `Connection: close`).